# How I can Change the orderBy firebase database parameter in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, firebase-realtime-database

I have this JSON object

```json
{
"message-100": {
    "chat_id": 69,
    "created_at": {
        "date": "2017-10-03 13:15:38.000000",
        "timezone": "UTC",
        "timezone_type": 3
    },
    "file": "",
    "message": "How r u?",
    "message_id": 100,
    "sender": 7
},
"message-101": {
    "chat_id": 69,
    "created_at": {
        "date": "2017-10-03 13:15:59.000000",
        "timezone": "UTC",
        "timezone_type": 3
    },
    "file": "",
    "message": "fine ...",
    "message_id": 101,
    "sender": 28
},
"message-89": {
    "chat_id": 69,
    "created_at": {
        "date": "2017-10-03 11:23:19.000000",
        "timezone": "UTC",
        "timezone_type": 3
    },
    "file": "",
    "message": "How r u?",
    "message_id": 89,
    "sender": 28
},
"message-90": {
    "chat_id": 69,
    "created_at": {
        "date": "2017-10-03 11:23:52.000000",
        "timezone": "UTC",
        "timezone_type": 3
    },
    "file": "",
    "message": "test",
    "message_id": 90,
    "sender": 7
}}
```

How can I order it using `orderBy`?  I mean that retrieve JSON object sorted in ascending order:

```
message-89
message-90 
message-100
message-101
```

Here is the firebase database code in Delphi:

```
procedure TFirebaseChatFacade.StartListenChat;
begin
  Run := True;
  TTask.Run(
    procedure
    var
      FFC: IFirebaseDatabase;
      Response: IFirebaseResponse;
      I: Integer;
      QueryParams: TDictionary<string, string>;
    begin
      FFC := TFirebaseDatabase.Create;
      FFC.SetBaseURI(FBaseURI);
      FFC.SetToken(FToken);
      QueryParams := TDictionary<string, string>.Create;
      try
        QueryParams.Add('orderBy', '"$key"'); // How I can change this parameter ???
        QueryParams.Add('limitToLast', '20');
        //////////////////////////////////////////

      finally
        QueryParams.Free;
      end;
    end);
end;
```

I try to change the `orderBy` parameter, but every time I get an exception telling me it's wrong:

```json
{"error":"Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \"key\", for path \"/chats/chat-69\", to the rules"}

{"error":"Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \".value\", for path \"/chats/chat-69\", to the rules"}

{"error":"orderBy must be a valid JSON encoded path"}

{"error":"Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \"message_id\", for path \"/chats/chat-69\", to the rules"}
```

How I can change it?

Comment: Seems like it is already ordered - given that the keys are strings they are ordered alphabetically.

Comment: it's order like this 
message-100, 
message-101, 
message-99,
message-98,
message-97,

I need to order it ascending  by the `message_id` ..

Comment: @UweRaabe ('orderByChild', '"message_id"') , Why this format not work,

How I can ordering it by `child` ?

Comment: @junior.programmer: have you tried removing the extra double-quotes around `message_id`? `QueryParams.Add('orderByChild', 'message_id')`

Comment: @RemyLebeau I try , and I got this exception
`{"error":"orderBy must be defined when other query parameters are defined"}`

Comment: @junior.programmer: And if you use `orderBy` instead, what happens? `QueryParams.Add('orderBy', 'message_id')`

Comment: @RemyLebeau `{"error":"orderBy must be a valid JSON encoded path"}`

Comment: @junior.programmer: Looking at the [source code for `TFirebaseRequest`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spinettaro/Firebase4Delphi/master/sources/Firebase.Request.pas), its `EncodeQueryParams()` method is using `TNetEncoding.URL.URLDecode()` instead of `TNetEncoding.URL.Encode()`. I wonder if that is causing the problem.  I have filed a [bug report](https://github.com/spinettaro/Firebase4Delphi/issues/7) about that

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you, I have to try to change the method of store data in firebase database .

Comment: Have you tried to use the Firebase Open Source Library for Delphi FB4D? github.com/SchneiderInfosystems/FB4D or from GetIt

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this error:  `{"error":"Index not defined, add \".indexOn\": \"key\", for path \"/chats/chat-69\", to the rules"}`

by accessing your Firebase/Databse/Rules and changing to something like that:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "yourdata": {
      ".indexOn": ["message_id"]
    } 
  }
}
```